# Data binding an object not being set?

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js, data-binding

Below is a link to the page. It may help with the resolution.

In the first question when you get the answer wrong the correctAnswer text does not appear. On every other question the correct answer text appears. I'm not sure why its loosing the object (correctAnswer).

The object gets set here.

```
      _private.questionIndex.subscribe(function (i) {

            if (i > -1 && i < self.questions.length) {

                var question = self.questions[i];

                var correctAnswer = null;

                for (var j = 0; j < question.Answers.length; ++j) {
                    if (question.Answers[j].IsCorrect) {
                        correctAnswer = question.Answers[j];
                        break;
                    }
                }

                self.correctAnswer(correctAnswer);
                self.currentQuestion(question);
            }
```

Im attempting to bind to the correctAnswer here. This always apears null for the first question. WHY? How can I fix this?

```
 <h3 class="qaRepeat correctAnswer" data-bind="html: correctAnswer() ? correctAnswer().Text : null"></h3>
```

Link the the flash cards as a reference.

https://www.wisc-online.com/GammaPlus/Content/FlashcardDownloadTemplate/index.html

Comment: try this` <h3 class="qaRepeat correctAnswer" data-bind="html: correctAnswer() ? correctAnswer() : ' ' "></h3>`

Comment: According to your binding, correct answer is just `0`, so there's no Text property on it (`ko.dataFor($0).correctAnswer()`) Could it be that you have all this logic within KO subscribe, which probably isn't fired for the first time (it has default value) ? Shouldn't you initialize it with `_private.questionIndex(-1)` and not `_private.questionIndex()`?

Comment: Tried usign this _private.questionIndex(-1) in a few locations with no success. What function is that line in?